# SQL IN operator in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am getting an error while binding a gridview. I want to select multiple records from database using SQL IN operator. Please help me to overcome this problem.

### aspx.cs code

```
    string codeId = "4,3,5,7";
    int[] result = codeId.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();


    string Qry = "select CodeId,Code,AccountHead,Rate from AccountHeads Where CodeId IN " + result;         //Getting error here     
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(Qry, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    adp.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.EmptyDataText = "no records founds";
        GridView1.DataBind();
        //Hide Gridview columns
        GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;

    }
```

Comment: You don't need to parse it to int array. Just use `codeId` string: `string Qry = "select CodeId,Code,AccountHead,Rate from AccountHeads Where CodeId IN (" + codeId +")" ;`

Comment: Don't answer in comments please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to split your string with `,` and use `IEnumerable.Select` to select `int` values.

You *already* have a nicely formatted string for [`IN` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx). You just need to use your values in `()` like;

```
string Qry = string.Format(@"select CodeId,Code,AccountHead,Rate
                             from AccountHeads Where CodeId IN ({0})",
                             codeId);
```

Comment: @Apurba [You have a moral obligation to introduce the OP to Bobby Tables.](http://xkcd.com/327/)